# How to use STDIN from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

How can I implement something like

```
$ echo "hello" | my_app
```

with usage of Python's subprocess?

subprocess.Popen() expects a pipe or a file handle for STDIN. But I want to provide STDIN for the called program via a variable. So something like

```
myinput = "hello"
subprocess.Popen("an_external_programm", stdin=myinput)
….
```

Comment: Have a look at `Popen.communicate()`. Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: Can you be clear about your use case? First off you look like you're piping "hello" to your script, in the second example it's a variable in your script.

Comment: I want to call an external tool from inside my Python script in the kind of the shell example but the content -- the "hello" from shell sxample, is coming from a Python variable.

Comment: Actually Popen.communicate() did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using `Popen.communicate()`

So some kind of pseudo code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(…)
proc.communicate(input="my_input_via_stdin")
```

Comment: the ellipsis character (...) kind of masks the solution in this answer :-)

Comment: What's the answer here? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a python script named myscript.py

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
     print(line)
```

in unix

echo 'hello' | myscript.py